# How to find button in dialog espresso

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, android-espresso

I have this popup. How can I press on QUIT button ?

I use string like this:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform((click()));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6kpN.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
onView(withText("QUIT"))
    .inRoot(isDialog())
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    .perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the UI-Automator with AndroidX, you can find the dialog and buttons.

It is a gradle dependency code.

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
}
```

You can reach the `QUIT` button with this code.

It is Kotlin code.

```
val button = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
                .findObject(
                    UiSelector().text(
                        activityTestRule
                            .activity
                            .getString(R.string.quit_button)
                            .toUpperCase()
                    )
                )

if (button.exists() && button.isEnabled) {
    button.click()
}
```